# Error "Answer This Question" button is missing on this question

Tags: bug

I was looking at this question [How long will it take Marie to saw another board into 3 pieces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/379927/75823)

Although I was not going to answer the the question (there are plenty of answers there already), I noticed this at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Then I noticed that the <kbd>Answer This Question</kbd> button is missing.

I have more than the required rep of 10, so why is the button missing.

Comment: That's interesting. Usually the 'protected by...' appears below the problem statement and above the answers, while the 'Answer this Question' bit appears below all the answers. What do you see below all the answers?

Comment: This is by design. "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation **on this site**", the association bonus does not count.

Comment: [Related meta.SO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937).

Comment: @J.M. That's good to know. Nice

Comment: I thought that was the point of the association bonus... to give an experienced user some reputation to work with on sister sites. So, you are given 100 rep points, but those rep points are not counted when considering what you can participate in.

Comment: @mixedmath - The horizontal rule you can see above the "Tan" area in my screenshot is the horizontal rule below the last answer. Below the text that says: *'...ask your own question.'* is some white-space then a medium weight black horizontal rule that is just above the top row of links in the footer.

Comment: @Kevin, the exception is only made for *protected* questions. You can ask questions, and answer unprotected questions, and even leave comments, but if you want to answer a protected question, you are expected to prove your mettle in other ways, first and foremost.

Comment: @Kevin: The association bonus is in order to let you have features like commenting and voting, because you obviously know how to do these things properly from other sites. But protection is meant to block unwanted "trivial" answers, and both "unwanted" and "trivial" are very subjective per community, so you are required to at least interact with the community in a positive manner before you are allowed to answer protected questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila @-J.M. - OK, I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your help, you have explained it perfectly.

(Quoted from comments above):

> The exception is only made for protected questions. You can ask questions, and answer unprotected questions, and even leave comments, but if you want to answer a protected question, you are expected to prove your mettle in other ways, first and foremost. – @J. M.

> The association bonus is in order to let you have features like commenting and voting, because you obviously know how to do these things properly from other sites. But protection is meant to block unwanted "trivial" answers, and both "unwanted" and "trivial" are very subjective per community, so you are required to at least interact with the community in a positive manner before you are allowed to answer protected questions. – @Asaf Karagila